# Use Material Design Icons in NPM Electron React project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass, material-design

I am trying to figure out how to use the Material Design Icons in an NPM Electron project. The project is setup with Webpack 4. According to the [Google Github page](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons/) it is simply installed by `npm install material-design-icons`. According to this [Angular issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2662#issuecomment-253448448) the path to the Material CSS file has to be added to the configuration. In my project I use React though and do not have any configuration file like this. So I thought importing the CSS from within the entry TypeScript file `App.tsx` like this `@import "~material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css";`, but when starting the project, Webpack does not find the file CSS file.

What must be done to use the Material Design Icons? Do I have to import them in the TypeScript/JavaScript files? Or do I have to setup Webpack for it?

Comment: It might be easier to use the [community version of material design icons](http://materialdesignicons.com/). You just import the icons from `@mdi/js` and there is a [react component](http://dev.materialdesignicons.com/getting-started/react) for rendering them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it meanwhile by importing the following into the `dependencies` section within the `package.json`:

```
"@material-ui/icons": "4.0.0",
```

Within a TypeScript React Component I for instance import the following:

```
import Add from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import Edit from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
```

which I can then use as return value from within the `render()` method:

```
<Add />
<Edit />
```